# GooglePlus Integration in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I already successfully integrated Google+ to my iOS app. But with the latest Apple store updates, the app is not allowed to open the browser to initiate the Google authentication using safari so i tried uiwebview for googleplus authentication and i am getting the access token but i cannot able to get the username and email address of the person logged in.Below i added my source,

```
NSString *client_id = @"***************************";;
NSString *secret = @"*******************************";
NSString *callbakc =  @"https://www.example.com/oauth2callback";;
NSString *scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription";
NSString *visibleactions = @"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize webview,isLogin,isReader;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];


NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&data-requestvisibleactions=%@",client_id,callbakc,scope,visibleactions];

[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
//    [indicator startAnimating];


NSLog(@"dgfduiussdiff %@ ",[[request URL] host]);

if ([[[request URL] host] isEqualToString:@"www.example.com"]) {

    // Extract oauth_verifier from URL query
    NSString* verifier = nil;
    NSArray* urlParams = [[[request URL] query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    for (NSString* param in urlParams) {
        NSArray* keyValue = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString* key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"code"]) {
            verifier = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];
            NSLog(@"verifier %@",verifier);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (verifier) {
        NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&redirect_uri=%@&grant_type=authorization_code", verifier,client_id,secret,callbakc];
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    } else {
        // ERROR!
    }

    [webView removeFromSuperview];

    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

    {
     NSError* error;

[receivedData appendData:data];


NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:receivedData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSLog(@"verifier %@",json);



 }
           - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:     (NSError *)error{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error]
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}  

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJsonParser *jResponse = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
NSDictionary *tokenData = [jResponse objectWithString:response];
//  WebServiceSocket *dconnection = [[WebServiceSocket alloc] init];
//   dconnection.delegate = self;

NSString *pdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=3&token=%@&secret=123&login=%@", [tokenData objectForKey:@"refresh_token"], self.isLogin];
//  NSString *pdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=3&token=%@&secret=123&login=%@",[tokenData accessToken.secret,self.isLogin];
//  [dconnection fetch:1 withPostdata:pdata withGetData:@"" isSilent:NO];


UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Google Access TOken"
                          message:pdata
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
 }
```

After executing the above source i getting the below response printed in nslog,

```
       verifier 4/kMcSZ2l-d_XXPo24NSdsMnugoP_MGDGPP4D5C1LRTfY
      2015-07-21 18:04:16.103 TechnoGerms.com[8981:189233] verifier {
     "access_token" =        "ya29.twG9kyMElyC8BgAxujF98WKN0BQ246Ey6zsKQEgSpKsNEb5JOS3QRl12La6XBy1geZnL";
"expires_in" = 3600;
      "id_token" = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImRhNjYyNWIzNmJjMDlkMzAwMzUzYjI4YTc0MWNlMTc1MjVhNGMzM2IifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTE0MjE4NDEwODI0NzM1ODkyMDg0IiwiYXpwIjoiMTY5NzY2MjI4OTY4LWtoNzI1dTFpZWdzNHN1bnFhOThhcHUxMHU4djhhcmFmLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhcmp1bkBsaW5rd2FyZS5pbiIsImF0X2hhc2giOiJQVnJxTURpNDViZnVGTm9kTmlsSFlRIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImF1ZCI6IjE2OTc2NjIyODk2OC1raDcyNXUxaWVnczRzdW5xYTk4YXB1MTB1OHY4YXJhZi5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImhkIjoibGlua3dhcmUuaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0Mzc0ODIwNTUsImV4cCI6MTQzNzQ4NTY1NX0.uSMrV8rOz4T4i5MhiCeQueNVGLv4NBLP-gtOcyow8t4BY9qvUO78sG4y0jPhbclPdX1kUZjzMVTeah2nU9fTYyl50dlj5FzWNy7LyM-a1GC2jEwkgWMgHdRPh6l7dqMrjQ9sU1rF-ZaiWfG7C9VJTJ76uEWRiSKKA9EFQtBil3xBtmDH07UMRxkbri2jBwaCPAWgjU8-dTarrxNESrwrO_nptaRzfGeaTyQBIYCAk6_9deXmblPgteER1OHoa65xb1OVK3ZPeZ3_dj9gjlXSyGp2ho5WIFGf2xRvW4XoROpUYqhLvrS3s-YrrZ8J5X5-3mafrs1qDjJYJogctbW7dg";
     "token_type" = Bearer;
   }
```

How i can get the username and email of person logged in by using the access token which i got above ? Please give any suggestions as i dont get any solution on google.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch the whole profile of the google+ user, you can use the below URL

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Then call the **GET** method. You will be given by an array containing authorized profile details.

Another method is that, if you want to store the authorized users email, its already present in the field as **id_token**. It is a base64_encoded data with some fields. If you decode the id yo will get some information about the user.For example in your result you found id_token as

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImRhNjYyNWIzNmJjMDlkMzAwMzUzYjI4YTc0MWNlMTc1MjVhNGMzM2IifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTE0MjE4NDEwODI0NzM1ODkyMDg0IiwiYXpwIjoiMTY5NzY2MjI4OTY4LWtoNzI1dTFpZWdzNHN1bnFhOThhcHUxMHU4djhhcmFmLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhcmp1bkBsaW5rd2FyZS5pbiIsImF0X2hhc2giOiJQVnJxTURpNDViZnVGTm9kTmlsSFlRIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImF1ZCI6IjE2OTc2NjIyODk2OC1raDcyNXUxaWVnczRzdW5xYTk4YXB1MTB1OHY4YXJhZi5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImhkIjoibGlua3dhcmUuaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0Mzc0ODIwNTUsImV4cCI6MTQzNzQ4NTY1NX0.uSMrV8rOz4T4i5MhiCeQueNVGLv4NBLP-gtOcyow8t4BY9qvUO78sG4y0jPhbclPdX1kUZjzMVTeah2nU9fTYyl50dlj5FzWNy7LyM-a1GC2jEwkgWMgHdRPh6l7dqMrjQ9sU1rF-ZaiWfG7C9VJTJ76uEWRiSKKA9EFQtBil3xBtmDH07UMRxkbri2jBwaCPAWgjU8-dTarrxNESrwrO_nptaRzfGeaTyQBIYCAk6_9deXmblPgteER1OHoa65xb1OVK3ZPeZ3_dj9gjlXSyGp2ho5WIFGf2xRvW4XoROpUYqhLvrS3s-YrrZ8J5X5-3mafrs1qDjJYJogctbW7dg
```

The above id_token contains 2 parts separated by '.'. The first part is thebase64_encoded key and the second part is metadata.

you can decode both the data as

```
$key=base64_decode(eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImRhNjYyNWIzNmJjMDlkMzAwMzUzYjI4YTc0MWNlMTc1MjVhNGMzM2IifQ)
```

will give you the key

```
$data=base64_decode(eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTE0MjE4NDEwODI0NzM1ODkyMDg0IiwiYXpwIjoiMTY5NzY2MjI4OTY4LWtoNzI1dTFpZWdzNHN1bnFhOThhcHUxMHU4djhhcmFmLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhcmp1bkBsaW5rd2FyZS5pbiIsImF0X2hhc2giOiJQVnJxTURpNDViZnVGTm9kTmlsSFlRIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImF1ZCI6IjE2OTc2NjIyODk2OC1raDcyNXUxaWVnczRzdW5xYTk4YXB1MTB1OHY4YXJhZi5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImhkIjoibGlua3dhcmUuaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0Mzc0ODIwNTUsImV4cCI6MTQzNzQ4NTY1NX0.uSMrV8rOz4T4i5MhiCeQueNVGLv4NBLP-gtOcyow8t4BY9qvUO78sG4y0jPhbclPdX1kUZjzMVTeah2nU9fTYyl50dlj5FzWNy7LyM-a1GC2jEwkgWMgHdRPh6l7dqMrjQ9sU1rF-ZaiWfG7C9VJTJ76uEWRiSKKA9EFQtBil3xBtmDH07UMRxkbri2jBwaCPAWgjU8-dTarrxNESrwrO_nptaRzfGeaTyQBIYCAk6_9deXmblPgteER1OHoa65xb1OVK3ZPeZ3_dj9gjlXSyGp2ho5WIFGf2xRvW4XoROpUYqhLvrS3s-YrrZ8J5X5-3mafrs1qDjJYJogctbW7dg)
```

will give you the metadata.

while decoding the data ,it will give the result as

```
{"iss":"accounts.google.com","sub":"114218410824735892084","azp":"169766228968-kh725u1iegs4sunqa98apu10u8v8araf.apps.googleusercontent.com","email":"arjun@linkware.in","at_hash":"PVrqMDi45bfuFNodNilHYQ","email_verified":true,"aud":"169766228968-kh725u1iegs4sunqa98apu10u8v8araf.apps.googleusercontent.com","hd":"linkware.in","iat":1437482055,"exp":1437485655}
```

Above result you can find the **email** filed. I hope this will help you.